# Plesk, incoming email not received

Tags: plesk, email, plesk-onyx

Here is the scenario,
I have plesk server running on a public IP.
I have have a domain pointing to that IP.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtaN5.png)

I used `mxtoolbox.com` which told, my mail.domain is pointing to my plesk server's IP.

The problem is that I am not able to receive mail in roundcube mail client.
Instead after 1 day I am getting mail from 'mailer-daemon@googlemail.com'
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9X8h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mail transfer protocol ports are closed, so it is not possible to receive mail:

```
# nmap -p 25,465,587 xx.xx.xxx.xx

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-20 21:39 +07
Nmap scan report for ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com (xx.xx.xxx.xx)
Host is up (0.17s latency).
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp  filtered smtp
465/tcp filtered smtps
587/tcp filtered submission

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.01 seconds
```

You need to allow incoming connections on the firewall.
Take a look at this article too - [Which Ports Need To Be Opened for all Plesk Services to Work with a Firewall?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213932745)

And this - [Amazon EC2 Security Groups for Linux Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Comment: Opened the port according to the first link, now it's working great.